# How can i disappear my popup when my condition satisfies?

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a popup whenever the image was not loaded but the problem scenario was, I am getting my popup even the image is loaded for the first time. So, I need to refresh it for disappearing it. How can I resolve it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXQXI.png)

The problem is that I have included the condition to check the image is loaded or not after the code of popup .so for the first time the popup was appearing even it satisfies the condition.

Help me out of it.

Comment: Please post the code here instead of providing images.

Comment: I am unable to add the code here as it is getting some indentation errors. If possible, can you do check with that image?

Comment: We don't know how you made your popup, or how you check if popup should be shown or not. So how could anyone help you without this basic information? Please provide a minimum reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

You should edit your question so as to include your code, so [your problem is reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:%7E:text=Help%20others%20reproduce%20the%20problem).

You can store your image as a variable and pass a function that hides your pop-up once the image is loaded.

```
var img1 = document.createElement("img");
    
    img1.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("**popup_ID").style.display='none'; 
    };
img1.src = "**your_image_path**"; //Edit suggested by @vanowm
```

Change "your_image_path" and "popup_ID" to match your code.

Comment: FYI, `onload` should be set before `src` change, otherwise in some situations it might miss the event

Answer (score 0):

Image has `complete` property that would tell if it finished loading or not. You can use that to show/hide popup on startup.
However to detect if image was successfully loaded or error occur, you'd need setup event listeners.

Here is a little example that does that:

```js
let timer;
const elLoadGood = document.getElementById("loadGood"),
      elLoadBad = document.getElementById("loadBad"),
      elPopup = document.getElementById("popup"),
      elImg = document.getElementById("myimage"),
      imgSrc = "https://cdn.spacetelescope.org/archives/images/publicationjpg/heic1502a.jpg?";

//set event handlers
elImg.onload = imageOnLoad;
elImg.onerror = imageOnError;

//load image
imageLoad(imgSrc);

elLoadGood.addEventListener("click", e=>
{
  //hide image
  elImg.removeAttribute("src");
  //load image
  imageLoad(imgSrc + Date());
});

elLoadBad.addEventListener("click", e=>
{
  //hide image
  elImg.removeAttribute("src");
  //load image
  imageLoad(Date());
});


function imageLoad(src)
{
  elPopup.classList.add("loading");
  elImg.classList.remove("error");
  elPopup.firstChild.textContent = "loading... please wait";
  //show popup
  imageFinished({});
  //load image
  elImg.src = src;
}

function imageFinished(img)
{
  //check if image finished loading
  if (img.complete)
  {
    elPopup.firstChild.textContent = "Finished loading. Close popup in 2 seconds";
    elPopup.classList.remove("loading");
  }
  clearTimeout(timer);
  //hide popup
  timer = setTimeout(() => elPopup.classList.toggle("hidden", !!img.complete), ~~img.complete * 2000);
}

function imageOnLoad(e)
{
  e.target.classList.remove("error");
  imageFinished(e.target);
}

function imageOnError(e)
{
  e.target.classList.add("error");
  imageFinished(e.target);
}
```

```css
div.img
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  line-height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -2;
}
img
{
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

img.error
{
  animation: error infinite 1s ease-in-out alternate;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

#popup
{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  line-height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: transparent;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: background-color 1s, opacity .5s;
}
#popup>span
{
  background-color: #ffffff7f;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 1em;
}
#popup.loading
{
  background-color: #0000007f;
}
#popup:not(.hidden) ~ *
{
  filter: blur(5px);
}

#popup.loading ~ *
{
  filter: blur(10px);
}
#popup.loading>span::before
{
  content: "";
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  line-height: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  animation: rotate infinite 1s linear;
  display: inline-block;
}

#popup.hidden
{
  opacity: 0;
}


@keyframes rotate {
    from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@keyframes error {
  to {box-shadow: 0 0 30px 0 red}
  from {box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 red}
}
```

```html
<button id="loadGood">load good image</button>
<button id="loadBad">load bad image</button>
<div id="popup" class="hidden"><span></span></div>
<div class="img"><img id="myimage"></div>
```